# How to shorten SPSS code for comparing multiple ICD codes to multiple diagnosis column

Tags: spss

This code selects cases which selects range of diagnosis (here range being 7567 to 75679) against multiple columns which stores the diagnosis codes (here DX1, DX2, DX3....etc.). Following works but it is pain to change the code every time when I am looking for new range of diagnosis. How do I shorten the code?

```
IF (RANGE(DX1,'7567','75679')  | RANGE(DX2,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX3,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX4,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX5,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX6,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX7,'7567','75679') |RANGE(DX8,'7567','75679')
| RANGE(DX9,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX10,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX11,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX12,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX13,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX14,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX15,'7567','75679')
| RANGE(DX16,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX17,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX18,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX19,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX20,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX21,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX22,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX23,'7567','75679') 
| RANGE(DX24,'7567','75679') | RANGE(DX25,'7567','75679'))ABDWALDEF=1.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: What is the exact list of codes you are trying to find ? If they are all strings, the `range` may not work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
count ABDWALDEF= DX1 to DX25 ('7567' thru'75679').
exe.
if ABDWALDEF>1 ABDWALDEF=1.
exe.
```

Personally, I would not reccomend string ranges in SPSS. You just need to make sure you know what you are doing, because string ranges are different from numerical ranges:

Take for example code 756780:

- **if DXs are numbers**. it will not fit into the (7567, 75679) range, because **756780>75679.**
- **if DXs are strings**, it will fit into the same range of strings, because strings are sorted based on the first character, then the second, and so on. Fist 4 characters are identical, and in 5th position there is "9">"8". So in strings, **"75679">"756780"**. Therefore, 756780 would be part of your range

As @eli-k mentioned in the comment, and you are really sure you want to work with numerica ranges, and not string ranges:

> if all the codes are really numbers in text format, you might as well
>   change them to numbers and everything gets easier:
>
> `alter type DX1 to DXn (f10).`

Comment: if all the codes are really numbers in text format, you might as well change them to numbers and everything gets easier: `alter type DX1 to DXn (f10).`

Comment: @eli-k: Very true. But I have seen systems of keeping track of categories just like that: 7567 is category code, and whatever comes after that is sub-category 75671 to 7567999. Maybe each digit place has a distinct meaning, and then sorting them as strings makes sense. This is why I mentioned the OP has to be sure what they are trying to achieve.

Comment: good call! if this is the situation, it would be possible to use `if char.substr(DXn,1,4)="7567" ...` to capture the category and all it's sub-categories. (put that in a loop for all the DXs)